# How to Convert Realm Cloud Anonymous User to Real User

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-cloud

If I create an anonymous user on [Realm Cloud](https://realm.io/products/realm-platform/) in Swift like this:

```
let credentials = SyncCredentials.anonymous()

SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: Constants.authURL) { user, error in
  //...
}
```

A user is created with a random **Provider ID** like `21483490cead296c6bc09ee40254d366` instead of an email address.

When the user decides later on to sign up for an account, is there a way to just update the provider ID to their email address and keep the same `identity` on their `SyncUser` record?

If not, how do I migrate their account? Do I have to manually migrate all their data to their new user account?

Comment: Hi, have you found a way to do it? thank you

Comment: Realm now supports anonymous login: https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/user-authentication

Comment: Yes I saw it, but it does not explain anywhere how to transform an authenticated user into an authenticated one without creating one more user

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I have been battling the same issue for a while now with no luck.

Comment: I just asked realm support essentially the same question and there answer was "yes, you have to migrate".  Not what we want, defeats the purpose of using realm for offline in the first place.  Started a bounty for a clever way to accomplish the migration or skip it altogether